# What is the name of this Call of Duty: United Offensive map?

Tags: call-of-duty, call-of-duty-united-offensive

I played *Call of Duty: United Offensive* in multiplayer for more than 4 years. I liked a particular map which has a two-storyed building with stairs inside and outside the building. There is a large courtyard surrounding the building with a high wall.

The setup was at a bright sunny day (spring season I guess). And the two teams available were American and German.

I can't recollect the map's name. It is ideal for 4-6 players.

Does anyone know the name of the map?

Comment: To add something more to the description: The setup was at a bright sunny day (spring season i guess). And the two teams available were American and German.

Comment: Do you remember which version of Call of Duty?

Comment: Call of duty: United offensive

Comment: Whoops, misclick.

Comment: For future historians, confirmed that Call of Duty: United Offensive is an expansion to the very first Call of Duty.  So this question is correctly tagged. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Duty_%28video_game%29

Comment: ^ Also for further future historians: Identifying items/characters (or maps, as it were), is [not a memory-based game identification issue](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10214/28182), as there is only a finite number of  items (maps) to search through therefore it does not suffer the same problems as memory-based game identification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. The map is [Clan Cottage](http://callofduty.filefront.com/file/Clan_Cottage;45553)

Answer (score 0):

maybe [Pavlov](http://www.statsgen.co.uk/statsgen2/map_COD1_mp_pavlov.html)?

Comment: Thanks Dav. But that's not the one. Infact, the map I was looking for is not among those which comes with the game. I downloaded it from somewhere :(